# AWS EKS pod keeps getting connection refuse after recreating on a new scale out node

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

**Env info and setup:**

- AWS
- EKS
- Auto Scaling Group (ASG)

**Action steps:**

1. scale out nodes from 3 to 4, lets name the node as node1-4, and multiple pods are running on node1-3
2. after the new node (node4) status is ready (by checking kubectl get node -n my-ns)
3. on aws console, protect node2-4 for scale in
4. scale in nodes from 4 to 3, node1 starts to terminate
5. pods that running on node1 starts to evict
6. pods evicted from node1 starts to re-create on node2-4

**Now tricky things happen:**

1. pod re-created on node2-3 (old nodes) becomes READY quickly, this is expected and normal
2. pod re-created on node4(newly scale out in action step 1) keep restarting, finally some got READY at 12 mins and the latest one got READY at 57 mins, which is quite abnormal
3. daemonset pod re-created on node4 becomes READY within 1 min.

**Investigation:**

1. check log for the pod that keep restarting, found:

> "Startup probe failed ..... http://x.x.x.x:8080/actuator/health connection refused"

2. once the pod becomes READY afer multiple restart, mannually delete it can get READY again quickly without restart
3. manually delete the pod that keeps restarting won't help

Any hints why this could happen?